# AVL tree implementation using non recursive insert method

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I'm learning to implement AVL tree and I'm stuck... Trying to implement Insert function non-recursively. it's been 3 days already and I'm lost. Here is my code... Hope someone can help me :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{ // WORKS
    public:
        Node *left, *right, *parent;
        int elem, height;

        Node(Node* l, Node* r, Node* p, int x, int h): left(l), right(r), parent(p), elem(x), height(h){}
        ~Node(){};
};

ostream&operator<<(ostream& os, const Node &n){  // WORKS
    os << "Node: " << n.left << ", " << n.right << ", " << n.parent << ", " << n.elem << ", " << n.height << ", my adress: " << &n << endl;
    return os;
}
```

Class AVL is pretty much BST, but my rotations are completely off!
I'm trying to insert elements like one would do it in BST and then do rotations to insure AVL tree properties

```
class AVL{
    public:
        Node* root{};
        AVL(){};
        ~AVL(){Destructor(root);}
        void Destructor(Node* node){
            if (node){
                Destructor(node->left);
                Destructor(node->right);
                delete node;
            }
        }
        void inorder(Node* node){ // WORKS
            if(node!=nullptr){
                inorder(node->left);
                cout << node->elem << " ";
                inorder(node->right);
            }
        }
        int minimum(Node* node){ // WORKS
            if(node->left!= nullptr) return minimum(node->left);
            return node->elem;
        }
        int maximum(Node* node){ // WORKS
            if(node->right!= nullptr) return maximum(node->right);
            return node->elem;
        }
        Node* predacessor(Node* node);
        Node* successor(Node* node);
        int height(Node* node){ 
            if(node == nullptr) return -1;
            return node->height;
        }
        int balance(Node* node){
            // cout << *node;
            int l_height = height(node->left);
            int r_height = height(node->right);
            int b_factor = l_height - r_height;
            // cout << ", Balance: " << b_factor << endl;
            return abs(b_factor);
        }
        Node* Insert(int x){ // inserting like its BST then checking for AVL proporties
            cout << "-------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Insert: " << x << endl;
            Node* current;
            if(root == nullptr){
                cout << "Importing root" << endl;
                Node* n = new Node( nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, x, 0);
                cout << *n;
                root = n;
            }else{
                Node* iter = root;
                while(iter != nullptr){
                    current = iter;
                    if(x > current->elem){
                        iter = iter->right;
                    }else{
                        iter = iter->left;
                    }
                }
                Node* n = new Node(nullptr, nullptr, current, x, current->height + 1);
                cout << *n ;
                cout << "Parent " << current->elem;
                if(x > current->elem){
                    current->right = n;
                    cout << " child right: " << n->elem << endl; 
                }else{
                    current->left = n;
                    cout << " child left: " << n->elem << endl;
                }
                // find one that makes AVL unbalanced then rotate
                cout << "For node: " << current->elem << " Balance: " << balance(current) << endl;
                Node* node = to_rotate(current);
                cout << *node;
                if(node != nullptr){ 
                    cout << "in rotation if! " << endl;
                    if(node->right->height > node->left->height){
                        leftRotate(node);
                    }else if(node->right->height < node->left->height){
                        rightRotate(node);
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        Node* to_rotate(Node* node){ // find node that makes AVL unbalanced
            if(balance(node) > 1 || node == nullptr){
                return node;
            }
            to_rotate(node->left);
            to_rotate(node->right);
        }

        void Delete(Node* node);

        void rightRotate(Node* &x){
            cout << "rightRotate: " << x->elem << endl;
            Node* y = x->left;
            Node* T = y->right;
            x->left = T;
            if(y->right != nullptr) y->right->parent = x;

            y->parent = x->parent;

            if(x->parent == nullptr){
                root = y;
            }else if(x = x->parent->right){
                x->parent->right = y;
            }else{
                x->parent->left = y;
            }
            y->right = x;
            x->parent = y;
        }
        void leftRotate(Node* &x){
            cout << "leftRotate: " << x->elem << endl;
            Node* y = x->right;
            Node* T = y->left;
            x->right = T;
            if(y->left != nullptr) y->left->parent = x;

            y->parent = x->parent;

            if(x->parent == nullptr){
                root = y;
            }else if(x == x->parent->left){
                x->parent->left = y;
            }else{
                x->parent->right = y;
            }   
            y->left = x;
            x->parent = y; 
        }

};

int main(){
    cout << "In main: " << endl;
    AVL avl;
    avl.Insert(1);
    avl.Insert(4);
    avl.Insert(9);
    avl.Insert(2);

    avl.inorder(avl.root);
    // cout << "Minimum: " << avl.minimum(avl.root) << endl;
    // cout << "Maximum: "<< avl.maximum(avl.root) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I know why I get segmentation folds but I cant figure out the right way to optimize rotations

Comment: (I'm sort of scared to think of non-recursive AVL `delete()`.)

Comment: Is there any description of the algorithms you're following that you can quote or provide a hyperlink to?

Comment: I can qoute. I'm trying to implement AVL like my professor presented, the idea is to insert nodes like in Binary search tree, and then look to balance it (using rotations that my professor presented as pseudo code, I think that I implemented those rotations just fine) and update heights so you get AVL tree structure. I tried my best to do so... I think that my problem is pinpointing where and what i should rotate using those right/left rotations

Comment: @greybeard can You help me?

Comment: You have neither quoted a description of the *insert* and *balance*/*rotate* algorithms you try to implement, nor provided a hyperlink: please do. The `struct` (`class` with *everything* `public`) shown does not feature a *balance* with values from -, 0, +. It features a `parent` and a `height` - there used to be times where this was considered an intolerable waste of space. You have a `Node* to_rotate()` where at least one path doesn't (explicitly) return a value - does your language system complain? Why are there separate open coded rotations in `rightRotate()` and `leftRotate()`?

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't quote a description of my algorithms, nor provide a link because this is something that I heard in data-structure lectures. I was hoping that You or anyone from stack overflow community could fix my code. Due to the fact that insert function doesn't work properly I can't test my functions so there could be a lot of mistakes. Function Node* to_rotate is supposed to return the Node in which AVL tree properties are invalid (guess it does not do that) so that by rotating Nodes I would get valid AVL tree. Anyways, I am fully aware of the situation. Thank You for your help! :)

Comment: Oh, I must have got your `I can qoute.` from five hours ago wrong. Let me think if I *want* to help. And what level of, hm, *coding ability* to assume.

Comment: I think I found documentation on this link https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf
under Red-black trees, 13-3 AVL trees

Comment: CLRS is guilty of suggesting to keep an integer data member *height* instead of a three-valued *balance*. *And* there is one very tricky part in *alters the subtree rooted at* x *to be height balanced*. I would have plugged [Rosetta code or](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/AVL_tree#C.2B.2B) even [en.wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL-tree#Insert) if I found the code presented tolerable for instructional purposes - alas, no dice.

Comment: Okay, I will try some other approach. Thank You very much for your patience and effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i think i got you an answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        int BalancingFactor;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

        Node(int Data=0){
            data=Data;
            left=NULL;
            right=NULL;
            BalancingFactor=0;
        }
};
class AVLTree{
    public:
        Node *root;
        vector<Node*> arr;
        AVLTree(){
            root=NULL;
        }
        void insert(int);
        Node* alterTree(Node* , int);
        Node* alterAfterDelete(Node * , int);
        void findImbalance(int);
        Node* LeftSubtreeOfLeftChild(Node* parent);
        Node *RightSubtreeOfRightChild(Node* parent);
        Node*RightSubtreeOfLeftChild(Node* parent);
        Node *LeftSubtreeOfRightChild(Node* parent);
        void findBalancingFactor(Node*);
        void updateBalancingFactor(Node*);
        void displayInorder(Node*);
        void displayPostorder(Node *);
        void displayPreorder(Node *);
        bool checkImbalance(Node* current);
        void findParentOfImbalance(int );
        void remove(int );
        vector<Node*> getRightMin(Node*);
        vector<Node*> getParentandChild(int);
};
Node* AVLTree::alterAfterDelete(Node* current,int value){
    if(value>current->data){
        if(current->left->BalancingFactor==0){
            current=LeftSubtreeOfLeftChild(current); //R0
        }
        if(current->left->BalancingFactor==1){
            current=LeftSubtreeOfLeftChild(current); //R1
        }
        if(current->left->BalancingFactor==-1){
            current=LeftSubtreeOfRightChild(current); //R-1
        }
    }
    else{
        if(current->right->BalancingFactor==0){
            current=RightSubtreeOfRightChild(current); //L0
        }
        if(current->right->BalancingFactor==-1){
            current=RightSubtreeOfRightChild(current); //L-1
        }
        if(current->right->BalancingFactor==1){
            current=RightSubtreeOfLeftChild(current);  //L1
        }
    }
    return current;
}
void AVLTree::findParentOfImbalance(int value){
    Node* Parent=NULL;
    Node* current=root;

    while(current!=NULL){

        if(current->data==value){
            break;
        }
        Parent=current;

        if(value>current->data){
                current=current->right;
        }
        else{

                current=current->left;

        }

    }
    arr.push_back(Parent);
}
bool AVLTree::checkImbalance(Node *current){
    if(current==NULL){
        return false;
    }
    checkImbalance(current->left);
    if(current->BalancingFactor>=2 || current->BalancingFactor<=-2){
        return true;
    }
    checkImbalance(current->right);
    return false;
}

void AVLTree::findImbalance(int value){
    Node* imbalance;
    Node* current=root;
    while(current!=NULL){
        if(current->data==value ){
            break;
        }
        if(current->data>value){
            if(current->BalancingFactor>1 || current->BalancingFactor<-1){
                imbalance=current;
            }
            current=current->left;
        }
        else{
            if(current->BalancingFactor>1 || current->BalancingFactor<-1){
                imbalance=current;
            }
            current=current->right;
        }

    }
    arr.push_back(imbalance);
}
Node* AVLTree::alterTree(Node* current,int key){
    if(current->BalancingFactor>1 && key<current->left->data){
        current=LeftSubtreeOfLeftChild(current);

    }
    else if(current->BalancingFactor<-1 && key>current->right->data){
        current=RightSubtreeOfRightChild(current);
    }
    else if(current->BalancingFactor>1 && key>current->left->data){
        current=RightSubtreeOfLeftChild(current);
    }
    else{
        current=LeftSubtreeOfRightChild(current);
    }

    return current;

}

void AVLTree::updateBalancingFactor(Node* current){
    if(current==NULL){
        return;
    }
    updateBalancingFactor(current->left);
    findBalancingFactor(current);
    updateBalancingFactor(current->right);
    return;

}
void AVLTree::findBalancingFactor(Node *current){
    int left=0;
    int right=0;
    Node* temp=current;
    while(temp->left!=NULL)
    {
        temp= temp->left;
        this->findBalancingFactor(temp);
        left++;
    }
    Node *temp2=current;
    while(temp2->right!=NULL)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->right;
        this->findBalancingFactor(temp2);
        right++;
    }

    current->BalancingFactor=left-right;
    return;
}

void AVLTree::insert(int value){
    if(root==NULL){
        root=new Node(value);
    }
    else{
        Node *current=root;
        while(true){
            if(value==current->data){
                break;
            }
            else{
                if(value<current->data){
                    if(current->left==NULL){
                        current->left=new Node(value);
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        current=current->left;
                    }

                }
                else{
                    if(current->right==NULL){
                        current->right=new Node(value);
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        current=current->right;
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }

    updateBalancingFactor(root);
    if(checkImbalance(root)==1){
        findImbalance(value);
        findParentOfImbalance(arr[0]->data);
        arr[0]=alterTree(arr[0],value);
        if(arr[1]!=NULL){
            if(arr[1]->data>arr[0]->data){
                arr[1]->left=arr[0];

            }
            else{
                arr[1]->right=arr[0];

            }
        }
        else{
            root=arr[0];
        }
    }


}
vector<Node*> AVLTree::getParentandChild(int value){
    vector<Node*> arr;
    Node* Parent=NULL;
    Node* current=root;

    while(current!=NULL){

        if(current->data==value){
            break;
        }
        Parent=current;

        if(value>current->data){
                current=current->right;
        }
        else{

                current=current->left;

        }

    }
    arr.push_back(current);
    arr.push_back(Parent);
    return arr;
}
vector<Node*> AVLTree::getRightMin(Node* get){
    Node* current=get->right;
    Node* temp=NULL;
    while(current->left!=NULL){
        temp=current;
        current=current->left;
    }
    vector<Node*> arr;
    arr.push_back(current);
    arr.push_back(temp);
    return arr;

}
void AVLTree::displayPostorder(Node *current){
    if(current==NULL){
        return;

    }
    displayPostorder((current->left));
    displayPostorder((current->right));
    cout<<current->data<<endl;
    return;

}
void AVLTree::displayPreorder(Node *current){
    if(current==NULL){
        return;
    }
    cout<<current->data<<endl;
    displayPreorder(current->left);
    displayPreorder(current->right);
}

void AVLTree::displayInorder(Node* current){
    if(current==NULL){
        return;
    }
    displayInorder(current->left);
    cout<<current->data<<endl;
    displayInorder(current->right);
    return;
}
Node* AVLTree::LeftSubtreeOfLeftChild(Node* parent){
    Node* temp=parent->left;
    parent->left=temp->right;
    temp->right=parent;
    return temp;
}
Node* AVLTree::RightSubtreeOfRightChild(Node* parent){
    Node* temp=parent->right;
    parent->right=temp->left;
    temp->left=parent;
    return temp;
}
Node* AVLTree::RightSubtreeOfLeftChild(Node* parent){
    parent->left=LeftSubtreeOfLeftChild(parent->left);
    parent=RightSubtreeOfLeftChild(parent);
    return parent;
}
Node* AVLTree::LeftSubtreeOfRightChild(Node* parent){
    parent->right=RightSubtreeOfRightChild(parent->right);
    parent=LeftSubtreeOfLeftChild(parent);
    return parent;
}
int main(){
    AVLTree hi;
    hi.insert(46);
    hi.insert(34);
    hi.insert(75);
    hi.insert(22);
    hi.insert(41);
    hi.insert(55);
    hi.insert(80);
    hi.insert(11);
    hi.insert(25);
    hi.insert(38);
    hi.insert(44);
    hi.insert(60);
    hi.insert(79);
    hi.insert(90);
    hi.insert(9);
    hi.insert(36);
    hi.insert(40);
    hi.insert(45);
    hi.insert(85);
    hi.insert(35);
    hi.displayInorder(hi.root);
}
```